# SQL Server - Select first row that meets criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables that contain IDs. There will be duplicate IDs in one of the tables and I only want to return one row for each matching ID in table B. For example:

Table A

```
+-----------+-----------+
| objectIdA | objectIdB |
+-----------+-----------+
|         1 |         A | 
|         1 |         B | 
|         1 |         D | 
|         5 |         F | 
+-----------+-----------+
```

Table B

```
+-----------+
| objectIdA |
+-----------+
|         1 |
|         5 |
+-----------+
```

Would return:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| objectIdA | objectIdB |
+-----------+-----------+
|         1 |         D | 
|         5 |         F | 
+-----------+-----------+
```

I only need one entry from Table A that matches Table B. It doesn't matter which row of table A is returned.

I'm using SQL Server.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need table B?

Comment: @drneel OP is looking for matching rows between TableA and TableB.

Comment: It just seems like given the sample data, all they would need is table A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT  B.objectIdA
           ,A.objectIdB
           ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.objectIdA ORDER BY A.objectIdB DESC) rn
    FROM TableA A 
    INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.objectIdA = B.objectIdA
   )
SELECT C.objectIdA
      ,C.objectIdB
FROM CTE 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Actually Table A will contain multiple other columns. I basically want to return all columns from Table A (that match the objectIdA in both tables)

Comment: Then you can change the outer select to get * from A and just use the CTE columns to join back onto A.

Comment: Is:
SELECT C.objectIdA
      ,C.objectIdB

Meant to be:
SELECT CTE.objectIdA
      ,CTE.objectIdB

Comment: Could the modified statement be posted to show how all column (and only all columns) from Table A are returned?
Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do so,by using a subselect for table a to get one entry per `objectIdA` group

```
select b.*,a.[objectIdB]
from b
join 
(select [objectIdA], max([objectIdB]) [objectIdB]
 from a group by [objectIdA]
) a 
on(b.[objectIdA] = a.[objectIdA])
```

### [`Fiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a779b/3)

**Edit deom comments** to get a whole row from tablea you can use a self join for tablea

```
select b.*,a.*
from b
join a
  on(b.[objectIdA] = a.[objectIdA])
join (select [objectIdA], max([objectIdB]) [objectIdB]
 from a group by [objectIdA]) a1 
  on(a.[objectIdA] = a1.[objectIdA] 
     and 
    a.[objectIdB] = a1.[objectIdB])
```

### [`Fiddle Demo 2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a9d905/2)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does what I need for the sample data. Do you know how I would modify it to show all of the columns in Table A (there are +10 other columns).
In my sample question I only had 2 columns in Table A.

Answer (score 1):

You should use PARTITION OVER to achieve the results.

```
   SELECT 
        t.objectIdA,
        t.objectIdB
    FROM (
      SELECT
         a.objectIdA,
         a.objectIdB,
        rowid = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.objectIdA ORDER BY a.objectIdB DESC)
      FROM TableA a
       INNER JOIN TableB b ON (a.objectIdA = b.objectIdA)
    ) t
    WHERE rowid <= 1
```

Fiddle Code: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2ccd/1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  MAX(b.ID) AS ID
       ,MAX(Value) AS Value
       ,MAX(OtherCol1) AS OtherCol1
       ,MAX(OtherCol2) AS OtherCol2
       ,MAX(OtherCol3) AS OtherCol3
FROM TblA AS a 
INNER JOIN TblB AS b ON a.TblBID = b.ID
GROUP BY TblBID
```

Table A

[image: Table A]

Table B

[image: Table B]

Table A Data

[image: Table A Data]

Table B Data

[image: Table B Data]

Query Result

[image: Query Result]