# Collapse multiple rows into a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I need to collapse multiple rows into one row based on the ID from just one column. For example:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| objectIdA | objectIdB |
+-----------+-----------+
|         1 |         A |
|         1 |         B |
|         1 |         D |
|         5 |         F |
|         5 |         L |
|         7 |         C |
+-----------+-----------+
```

So the result would be:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| objectIdA | objectIdB |
+-----------+-----------+
|         1 |         A |
|         5 |         L |
|         7 |         C |
+-----------+-----------+
```

I don't care which of the rows is returned from the collapse, once there is only 1.

Comment: You can use `<pre>` tag or `{}` button in the editor panel to indent your code.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: You could use `group by` clause combined with `min` or `max` functions. Just as in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25318623/298282).

Comment: I'm trying a different approach to solving the problem as it looks like I was unable to get a solution from the other post.

Comment: And `select objectIdA, max(objectIdB) from tableA group by objectIdA` not worked for you?.. Hey it's basic SQL!

Comment: select objectIdA, max(objectIdB) from tableA group by objectIdA
Returns duplicates of objectIdB. Also, I need all columns from the table (with no additional ones).

Comment: Perhaps you could pursue your prior question to its logical conclusion rather than abandoning it. I see in your other question a lot of effort has been made including screenshots etc.

Comment: I agree. I had though that discussion of my first question had finished, as I hadn't clearly enough stated my problem. I'll know for future!
Although being able to perform the collapse mentioned here will be useful for some test cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT objectIdA
FROM your_table;
```

Comment: DISTINCT cant be used here as both the columns should be part of the output

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't care which row is returned

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE (objectIdA int, objectIdB varchar(1));

INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES (1, 'A');
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES (1, 'B');
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES (1, 'D');
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES (5, 'F');
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES (5, 'L');
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES (7, 'C');

SELECT objectIdA, MIN(objectIdB) AS objectIdB
 FROM @myTable
 GROUP BY objectIdA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PARTITION OVER. The following query will do what you want. You can tweak the ORDER BY to exactly retrieve either first or last record, if you wish

```
SELECT 
        t.objectIdA,
        t.objectIdB
    FROM (
      SELECT 
        raw.objectIdA,
        raw.objectIdB,
        rowid = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY raw.objectIdA ORDER BY raw.objectIdA)
      FROM yourTable raw
    ) t
    WHERE rowid <= 1
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/60092/10